# How to use an object that's in another module?

Tags: vba

completely new to VBA here. I have a problem getting my code running. In the first module, it works fine and creates a new Excel sheet formatted with the data I want. In the second module I want to be able to create a table that can sort it. I ran the code and I got a run-time error of '91': Object variable or with block variable not set.

If anybody could offer some advice, would greatly appreciate it, thanks!

1st Module:

```
Option Explicit

Public wsFormatted As Workbook


Sub FormatData()

'Create new worksheet named "Formatted"

Set wsFormatted = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add

wsFormatted.Name = "Formatted"

End Sub
```

Second Module:

```
Option Explicit

Sub createTable()

Dim Formatted As Workbook

Formatted.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("A1:M105"), , xlYes).Name = "SortedTable"

End Sub
```

Comment: What is `Formatted`?

Comment: @BigBen it's a new sheet with the data I want formatted

Comment: Yes, but why do you have `wsFormatted` previously?

Comment: Does this need to be two separate subs?

Comment: You are setting a worksheet to a workbook variable

Comment: `wsFormatted` should be declared `As Worksheet`. And `Formatted` is not the same as `wsFormatted`.

Comment: @urdearboy no it doesnt have to be, I just made it separate because the first module takes awhile to load in and format all the data. Which one is the worksheet and which is the workbook variable?

Comment: @BigBen so I dont need to Set wsFormatted = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add?

Comment: You can post the slow part of your macro for review - it may be slow by design. Note here though. There is a site for code review :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with segregating parts of macros into individual components. However, maybe doing it one sub will help you see where you went wrong.

1. Declare worksheet variable
2. Add and `Set` worksheet
3. Rename worksheet
4. Add listobject

Notice none of these are making changes to the workbook object (like workbook name, location, etc.), but your public variable was `wsFromatted as Workbook`. You are making changes to a sub-property of the workbook: the worksheet. Therefore, your variable `wsFormatted` should be type `Worksheet`

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub FormatData()

Dim wsFormatted As Worksheet
Set wsFormatted = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
wsFormatted.Name = "Formatted"
wsFormatted.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("A1:M105"), , xlYes).Name = "SortedTable"

End Sub
```